# How to show allertbox on completion of Percentage indicator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I want to show an alertbox when my progress indicator reached 100%. Is there any way to do it in flutter?

```dart
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var progressValue = (100 * controller.value).toInt();
    return FittedBox(
      child: CircularPercentIndicator(
          percent: controller.value,
          animation: true,
          animationDuration: 1000,
          progressColor: colorProgressIndicatorProgress,
          radius: widget.radius,
          center: Text("$progressValue% ${widget.centerText}",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
      // child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can done listening on `onChanged` like this

```dart
class ASDA extends StatefulWidget {
  const ASDA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ASDA> createState() => _ASDAState();
}

class _ASDAState extends State<ASDA> {
  double value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: value,
            onChanged: (v) {
              setState(() {
                value = v;
              });

              if (v == 1) {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("100%"),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no onChanged() method for CircularPercentIndicator()
I am using percent_indicator: ^4.0.1 library.

Comment: try using `percent` value

Comment: but how to trigger this. there is no trigger methods like onPressed or onChanged